# How do you reset ASP.Net AJAX cascading dropdown control (client side)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, drop-down-menu

The cascading dropdown control works great except that I am unable to figure out a way to reset the dropdown client-side (in Javascript)

My set up is something like this

```
DD1
DD2
DD3
DD4
```

each `DD` is dependent on the previous `DD` and uses webservice to load them.

On change of `DD3` I need to reset `DD4` but the previous selection stays.

Can this be done? I tried clearing the value in the supporting hidden input control (cddTest_ClientState) in vain

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dd1" runat="server" onChange="ondd1ChangeHandler(this)>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="dd2" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
<cc1:CascadingDropDown ID="cdd2" runat="server" Category="Cat1"
    ParentControlID="dd1" PromptText="(Select Option)" ServiceMethod="GetOptions"
    ServicePath="Services/GetOptions.asmx" TargetControlID="dd2">
</cc1:CascadingDropDown>

<script type='text/javascript>
    function ondd1ChangeHandler(dd){
        var dd2=$get('dd2');
        dd2.selectedIndex=0;
        var cdd=$find('cdd2');
        if(cdd!=null){
            cdd.set_SelectedValue('','');
            cdd._onParentChange(null,false);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps